# Add a marker on Google Map with Latitude and Longitude Values

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm currently developing an Android App that has Google Map in it. 
The application can now retrieve the longitude and latitude values of the current location of the user. But the problem is, it should add a marker on the map using these values.

Comment: There's an example here: http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/03/steps-to-place-marker-in-map-overlay.html